# is this python Timer usage safe?

Tags: python, timer

I have a small class with a timer, but don't have anything for the timer to do when it expires.  Since Timer extends Thread, I get all I want to know from calling timer.isAlive().  Since Timer requires a function parameter, I'm looking for an anonymous 'nop' function that doesn't clutter the class, and came up with this;

```
  def ready(self, node):
    def nop(): pass
    delay = node.find('delay')
    seconds = float(delay.get('seconds'))
    self.timer = Timer(seconds, nop)
    return True;
```

It seems to work with my little test programs. Having not tried this before, or seen this as an example anywhere, I'm wondering, is this truly safe?

Comment: You really don't need that semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine.  Functions doing nothing aren't dangerous -- they just do nothing.  Using a lambda function would make the code a bit more concise:

```
self.timer = Timer(seconds, lambda: None)
```